# How to use an input box with an keyUp function to dynamically display matched list elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created a site in codepen.io that links to a list of twitch streams, then displays the online streamers in one tab, offline in another, and both in a third.  Each user is appended to the appropriate tab via a JQuery function.  (this works)

I'm attempting to search through the tab with an input element and display the matched twitch streams.

I've gotten as far as using an at keyup function on the text element, but I do not know how to apply this to a tab that has its elements appended to it.  The only similar questions asked have to do with simple lists, not tabs.

Thanks for any and all help.

This is where I've gotten so far:

The html:

```
<h1 id="head">
  <input type="text" id="inputBox" class="rounded" value="">
</h1>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id = "list">
    <li class="nav active" id ="AllTab"><a href ="#All" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">All</a></li>
    <li class="nav" id ="OnlineTab"><a href="#Online" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Online</a></li>
    <li class="nav" id="OfflineTab"><a href="#Offline" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Offline</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content" id="stuff">
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="All">

    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="Online">

    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="Offline" >

    </div>

 </div>
```

The javascript in question:

```
 $('#inputBox').keyup(function(){
      var valThis = $(this).val();
      $('.nav active').each(function(){
        var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
        (text.indexOf(valThis) != -1) ? $(this).show() : $(this).hide();         
      });
    });
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be selecting tab content like $('#Online') rather than the tab list item $('.nav active') ?  Reference: [jQuery Tabs](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2rqckroL/2/)

```
    $('#inputBox').keyup(function () {
    var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $('.nav,.tab-pane').hide();
    $('.nav').each(function () {
        var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
        if (text.indexOf(valThis) > -1) {
            $(this).show();
           $('#'+$(this).attr("id").replace('Tab','')).show();
        } else {
            $(this).hide();
             $('#'+$(this).attr("id").replace('Tab','')).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Also Angular JS makes impementing such type of functionalities on large data very easy. You might want to check it out.

Comment: This is a step forward for sure.  Now the tab headers will be searched through instead of the list elements though.  So if I type, 'a', the 'All' tab will show and the rest are hidden.  However, I need to search through the elements that the 'All' (or whichever tab is active) show.  Still though, I'm getting some results now, so thank you.  I'm trying to fiddle around with it some more.  Edit:  I just saw that you recommended Angular.JS.  I'm going through that now.  I definitely have a huge gap in understanding what I'm doing right now, so I'm gonna head that route as well.

Comment: @BurningDaisies which elements are you talking about? Is there any more HTML code ? Can you share what exactly do you mean by all elements?

Comment: I think you are right.  I just added the html of the divs that I add the streams to.  I'm attempting to use those div ids as the hide and shows instead of the tabs.

Comment: @BurningDaisies - here is your updated code which you need [http://jsfiddle.net/2rqckroL/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/2rqckroL/2/). Updating answer as well